# Prevent SQL injection in Google Sign In

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, google-signin

My website appears to have suffered a few MySQL injection attacks in the last couple of days, causing some (thankfully mostly repairable) damage to my user database. I discovered this because my website was logging a new user with the userid:

```
999999.9 /**/uNiOn/**/aLl /**/sElEcT 0x39313335313
```

(I'm not at all sure what the above query was designed to do. The actual damage involved changing every row of my users table to make it look like every user had logged in recently. Bizarre, but suggests they did more attacks than the one my log picked up.)

This was being done via my Google Sign In button. My signin button uses javascript to communicate with Google, then sends via GET the returned userid through to my next page (where I decide whether to log them in or register a new account). It's this GET query that is being injected.

I use MySQLi to make my SQL queries. I am pretty competent with PHP and have used MySQL for years, but am very much an amateur developer. I would really appreciate any advice on how to secure this. Thank you.

EDIT:

Here's an example of my code, as requested:

```
$db = new mysqli('localhost', 'XXX', 'XXX', 'seatingplan');

if($db->connect_errno > 0){
    die('Unable to connect to database [' . $db->connect_error . ']');
}

$sql = <<<SQL
    SELECT *
    FROM `users`   
    WHERE `userid` = '$userid'
SQL;

if(!$result = $db->query($sql)){
    die('There was an error running the query [' . $db->error . ']');
}


while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    $useridcheck = $row['userid'] ;
    $existingImageUrl = $row['image'] ;
}

$lastlogin = date("Y-m-d H:i:s") ;

$sql = <<<SQL
    UPDATE `users`
    SET `lastlogin` = '$lastlogin',
    `logins` = `logins` + 1
    WHERE `userid` = '$userid'
SQL;


if(!$result = $db->query($sql)){
    die('There was an error running the query [' . $db->error . ']');
}
```

Comment: One idea I've had could be to validate the GET to ensure it looks like a Google userid. Does this sound like a sensible thing to do?

Comment: We need code to say anything about this.

Comment: @NorbertvanNobelen Sorry, I've added an example

Comment: Why are you doing `SELECT * FROM \`users\` WHERE \`userid\` = '$userid'`? Can you not bind that value (`$userid`)?

Comment: Same with this, you should bind parameter: `UPDATE \`users\` SET \`lastlogin\` = '$lastlogin', \`logins\` = \`logins\` + 1 WHERE \`userid\` = '$userid'` on `$userid`

Comment: This is why writing your own login system is usually a bad idea. Even more experienced developers will make a tiny mistake that someone can exploit because doing these things air-tight is hard. Remember any modern [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) usually comes with some kind of login system. [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) has a very robust [authentication module](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/authentication) which does everything you should need out of the box.

Comment: If you're concerned about people hacking your site, which is a very reasonable thing to worry about, **do not** use `die`. It can reveal a lot of information about the nature of your site to attackers, like file paths and table names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQL Injection occurs when using not protected string concatenation or replacement. MySQLi and (better) PDO have options to protect against such problems by taking care that the string replacement is done in a safe manner. Safe meaning that the data in the string is escaped such that malicious code does not get executed.

The problem code in the code above is:

```
$sql = <<<SQL
    UPDATE `users`
    SET `lastlogin` = '$lastlogin',
    `logins` = `logins` + 1
    WHERE `userid` = '$userid'
SQL;
```

In here `$lastLogin` and `$userid` can be abused if the developer did not check those values.

With php PDO the query would look like this:

```
$sql = "UPDATE `users`
    SET `lastlogin` = :lastlogin,
    `logins` = `logins` + 1
    WHERE `userid` = :userid"
```

The `:lastlogin` and `:userid` are then bound using pdo providing a safe way of substituting your parameters

Comment: `mysqli` can do this but since it doesn't support named placeholders you have to use `?`. PDO is a lot more friendly because of this feature, plus PDO isn't MySQL specific.

Comment: @tadman I have a lot of code to update, so will probably stick to MySQLi to reduce the changes I have to make. However, I can't figure out whether I'm still able to use this code to return results in the format `$row['whatever']`.

`while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    $useridcheck = $row['userid'] ;
    $existingImageUrl = $row['image'] ;
}`

Comment: Every guide I read to using parameterised msqli tells me to bind the results using `$statement->bind_result(blah)`. Again, I'd rather avoid doing this, as it would lead to further big code changes.

Comment: Hi Rob, it actually prevents big code changes: At this moment you would have to implement validation and security on your input parameters, in both mysqli and PDO this is already done for you, thus saving a lot of code. It will also look way more readable especially when you use this on larger SQL statements.

Comment: @rob  `mysqli` is a lot more fussy to work with than PDO, and it's also MySQL specific. PDO is more generic, and the named placeholders feature alone makes it worth every bit of effort to switch over. The queries are abundantly clear and mistakes are more obvious.